# How to assign permission to a user in unix, since i am unable to create or use any command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
$ touch 1
touch: cannot touch ‘1’: Permission denied
$ who
root     pts/5        2015-01-30 16:48 (43.68.41.127)
test     pts/7        2015-01-30 16:56 (43.68.41.127)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chown` command to give user permission to a specific user. like as follows,

```
chown username file
chown username folder
chown -R username folder #recursive
```

Comment: In below script i am trying to print lines using sed but its not working can you help @Skynet 
#!/bin/bash
let x=`cat users | wc -l`
echo $x
let y=$x-10
echo $y
#sed -n '10,$p' users
sed -n '$y,$p' users >> tmp

Comment: @sammyB ask it as another question, I hope your main question had been answered. I will answer you there.

Comment: @sammyB accept the answer, if your problem solved.